# What is the best way to update my local files with Git?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

It has been one week since I have been working on a code at my workplace, and today I noticed that my files are outdated.

What step-by-step process should I follow to perform the following actions:

- Update my local files with the ones in the "development" branch on GitLab.
- Push the files I edited during the week.

Should I do it in this order? Update my local files first and then push the edited files?

---

Note: The branch I'm working on is called "dev_rafael," and the main project branch is called "development."

Comment: It's also common to `rebase` the dev branch onto the remote development solving the possible conflicts and then push. You'll also rebase before merging. But it's a bit more advanced technique for which some familiarity with git is needed.

Answer (score 0):

1. merge with your branch & development brance
2. fetch origin
3. pull origin
4. if there is merge conflict , solve this
5. commit to your brach
6. push to your branch
7. repeat only step 1

summary: 1st combine  online branches(step1,7) , 2nd get your online copy in local(step 2,3,4), 3rd send your local copy to online(step 5,6)

Answer (score 0):

## Update your branch with Gitlab’s `development` changes

1. Make sure you commit every local change (that you want to push) in your `dev_rafael` branch.
2. Then, push them with:

```bash
git push origin dev_rafael
```

3. Merge changes from `development` into your local `dev_rafael` branch:

```bash
git pull origin development
```

4. Push your branch with everything in it again with:

```bash
git push origin dev_rafael
```

After that, if you want to put your changes into `development`, it depends on your project workflow:

## If your project is *not* using Gitlab’s Merge Requests

The simplest if your are not too familiar with Git is:

```bash
git checkout development
git pull origin development
git merge dev_rafael
git push origin development
```

(That requires that your are allowed to push on `development` branch directly)

**Explanation:** First command switches to `development` branch, second retrieves changes from Gitlab, third merges your local developments from `dev_rafael` into `development`, last one pushes it to Gitlab, on `development` branch.

## If your project *is* using Gitlab’s Merge Requests

```bash
git push origin dev_rafael
```

Then go to Gitlab and [create a merge request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/creating_merge_requests.html) with:

- `dev_rafael` as Source Branch
- `development` as Target Branch

Get it approved and merged by your team.
Done!